# Django Admin Inline & TabularInline – Appending ordered text fields with a sql database structure

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have read and have tried some of the examples in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/  in regard to appending additional objects.

Essentially what I want is a Question to have multiple Answers and within the Admin Question area with the ability to get a [+] button to add additional questions.

I want to get that working first; but down the road I also want to do the following:

- Ordered list of Answers: that is, ranked ordering to the questions.
- Ability to repeat Answers in the ordered list

**In models.py file**

```html
from django.db import models
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**In admin.py file:**

```html
From .models import (
Question,
Answer,
)

class AnswerTabularinline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=Answer

class QuestinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerTabularinline]
    class Meta:
        model = Question

admin.site.register(Question, QuestinAdmin)
admin.site.register(Answer)
```

---

This is a fairly standard implementation of tabular inline; however, I am linking it to a SQL database and I have added the following tables:

```html
CREATE TABLE "ModME_question" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "name"  TEXT,
    "text"  TEXT,
    "answer"    INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("answer") REFERENCES "ModMe_Answer"("id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "ModMe_Answer" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "text"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ordering in Meta of your model

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('answer',)
```